# Referencing items while using uncover

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, lists, itemize

I am writing a presentation (using `beamer`) for a seminar and I just faced a problem I can't handle.

On one slide, I have a big equation and then use an `uncover`-list to explain all the elements in detail. Later on, I want to have a reference to one particular explanation so that I can click it and go back to the equation, with the explanation highlighted.

However, the reference points to the beginning of the slide (i.e. equation shown, items semi-transparent). But I want to go to the specific slide - the one with a specific `item` of the `itemize` highlighted.

Below is a minimal example of the problem I have encountered. How do I cope with it?

```
\begin{frame}
  % big nasty equation here
  \begin{itemize}
    % explanations for parts of the equation here
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \uncover<2>{
      \item first item
    }
    \uncover<3>{
      \item second item
    }
    \uncover<4>{
      \item third item
    }
    \uncover<5>{
      \item \label{special_item} fourth item
    }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
% skipping some frames here
\begin{frame}
  \ref{special_item}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in Section 11 of the [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  % big nasty equation here
  \begin{itemize}
    % explanations for parts of the equation here
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \uncover<2>{
      \item first item
    }
    \uncover<3>{
      \item second item
    }
    \uncover<4>{
      \item third item
    }
    \uncover<5>{
        \hypertarget<5>{special_item}{}
      \item fourth item
    }
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
% skipping some frames here
\begin{frame}
  \hyperlink{special_item}{Link}
  \ref{special_item}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason, `\ref{special_item}` complains about the reference being undefined. However, the `\hyperlink{}{}` works. I prefer this solution to the one presented by percusse, because the declaration of the 'sub-slide' the link has to point to is closer to the slide itself, making it easier to maintain. Oh, an thank you for pointing to the doc. I guess you're entitled to say RTFM now :)

Answer (score 5):

It's better to refer to the frames/slides rather than items. Also you can feed the labels as options to the `frame` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=eqframe]
  \[
    (Big)^{nasty}\sum quation= Here
    \]
  \begin{itemize}
    % explanations for parts of the equation here
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \uncover<2>{
      \item first item
    }
    \uncover<3>{
      \item second item
    }
    \uncover<4>{
      \item third item
    }
    \uncover<5>{
      \item fourth item
    }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
% skipping some frames here
\begin{frame}
  \hyperlink{eqframe<5>}{Fourth item}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works nicely, but the other answer seems more straight-forward and 'easier to maintain'.

Comment: @dare2be No problem at all :)