# How to label a special slide instead of the whole frame in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referencing items while using uncover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38880/referencing-items-while-using-uncover)

Is it possible in a `beamer` presentation to achieve that a hyperlink points to a certain slide of a frame? For example, in the MWE below I would like the hyperlink to point to the second slide of the first frame. For now, I can only achieve that it points to the first slide of the first frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document} 
  \begin{frame}[label=B]
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      \item<2-> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
      \item<3-> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame} 
  \begin{frame}
      AAAAAAAA \hyperlink{A}{\beamergotobutton{}}    
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Two examples and a link to manual: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38880/referencing-items-while-using-uncover Minor issue: they are mostly referred to slides instead of layers.

Comment: Thanks! Looks as if my question is a duplicate ... I have substituted *slide* for *layer*.

Comment: I would suggest that we either close my question or you make your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: duplicate sounds better if you don't mind.

Comment: No, it's OK for me. I suppose that my question is nevertheless still visible (and searchable) ... (since I think my question, title and MWE are clearer than in the other question).